# How can I change the date time formats in Perl?

Tags: perl

i want to convert the date time format to that i want.

how to convert the date time format from Fri Nov 21 2014 15:04:32 to 2014-11-21 15:04:32 ?

thanks

Comment: do you want to use and date modules or want to do in plain perl?

Comment: how to do in plain perl ?

Comment: `POSIX::strftime()` is in core, is that "plain"?

Comment: how to use strftime() to  convert datetime format from Fri Nov 21 2014 15:04:32 to 2014-11-21 15:04:32 ?

Comment: or have other method to convert datetime format from Fri Nov 21 2014 15:04:32 to 2014-11-21 15:04:32 ?

Answer (score 3):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been core Perl for many years.

Use `strptime` (string parse time) to parse your date/time string.

Use `strftime` (string format time) to format your date/time as you want it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;

# Formats are defined in "man strftime"
my $in_fmt  = '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S';
my $out_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my $in_date = 'Fri Nov 21 2014 15:04:32';

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($in_date, $in_fmt);
my $out_date = $date->strftime($out_fmt);

say $out_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = 'Fri Nov 21 2014 15:04:32';
my @months =('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec');
my ($day,$mon,$date,$year,$time) = split(' ',lc($str));
my %month_hash;
@month_hash{@months} = (1 .. 12);
print "$year-$month_hash{$mon}-$date $time";
```

try this its crude method but works for your requirements. use date::manip for flexible usage

Comment: Date::Manip is never a good suggestion. Time::Piece has been part of core Perl since 2007.

Comment: thank you Dave i used Date::Manip it long back, any how Time::Piece  will have a look, thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: Any solution where you start off having to build your own hash or list of month names is going to be terrible. There are functions for doing that parsing - in this case `strptime`. If you maintain your own hash, it won't localise properly.